# Get pixel values of a bitmap image in Android

Tags: android, pixel

I need to develop an android application which do some image processing on the image input. For this, I need to get the pixel values of the bitmap in either an array or an object. Can anyone help me to grab the pixel-level details of a bitmap image.

Thanks !

Comment: There's numerous related questions to the right side of yours (scroll down a bit) - have you browsed through those? It appears the answers there apply literally to yours. If not, please rephrase your question and try to highlight exactly what's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get pixel array of bitmap

```
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height);
```

every pixel/value in array will be represented as Color with ARGB value.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the value of on pixel do this
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);