# loop through each pixel in java android

Tags: java, android

I want to compare each pixel in jpg's File A and File B on an Android.  Images have same hxw.  Android doesn't support awt's BufferedImage.  Suggestions?  pseudo code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < a.getWidth(); x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < a.getHeight(); y++) {
        int rgb = a.getRGB(x, y);
        int rgb2 = b.getRGB(x, y);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960735/get-pixel-values-of-a-bitmap-image-in-android) that uses `Bitmap.getPixels`.

Answer (score 0):

public void getPixels (int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)